# Getting errors while integrating paypal advanced using PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I want to integrate Paypal Advanced into PHP.
After successfully passed the values and submit the form, have got an 
error message response from Paypal.
Error message is : RESPMSG=User authentication failed.

I have Used these codes :

```
$PF_HOST_ADDR = "https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com";
$post_data = 'USER=' . $PF_USER
              .  '&VENDOR= ' . $PF_USER
              .  '&PWD= ' . $PF_PWD
              .  '&PARTNER= ' . $PF_PARTNAR
              .  '&AMT=' . $PF_PACKAGE
              .  '&ACCT=' . $PF_CARD_NO
              .  '&ACCTTYPE='.$PF_CARD_TYPE
              .  '&CURRENCY='.$PF_CURRENCY_TYPE

              .  '&CVV2=' . $PF_CVV
              .  '&EXPDATE=' . $PF_EXP_DATE
              .  '&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y'
              .  '&SECURETOKENID=' . $PF_SECURE_TOKEN_ID
              .  '&CLIENTIP='. $PF_IP_ADDRESS
              .  '&TRXTYPE=S';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$PF_HOST_ADDR);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data); // Ready the Post data to Send ....

    $response = curl_exec($ch); //Getting Response from Server

    print_r($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$post_data` variable is querystring, so remove your whitespaces from next to VENDOR, PWD and PARNTER

It would be like this

```
$post_data = 'USER=' . $PF_USER
              .  '&VENDOR=' . $PF_USER
              .  '&PWD=' . $PF_PWD
              .  '&PARTNER=' . $PF_PARTNAR
              .  '&AMT=' . $PF_PACKAGE
              .  '&ACCT=' . $PF_CARD_NO
              .  '&ACCTTYPE='.$PF_CARD_TYPE
              .  '&CURRENCY='.$PF_CURRENCY_TYPE

              .  '&CVV2=' . $PF_CVV
              .  '&EXPDATE=' . $PF_EXP_DATE
              .  '&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y'
              .  '&SECURETOKENID=' . $PF_SECURE_TOKEN_ID
              .  '&CLIENTIP='. $PF_IP_ADDRESS
              .  '&TRXTYPE=S';
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggession. But same problem occurred

Comment: please check(print) your $post_data variable, maybe one of variables is null or wrong

Comment: USER=maxgold25&VENDOR=maxgold25&PWD=password&PARTNER=paypal&AMT=12.00&ACCT=4111111111111111&CVV2=205&EXPDATE=1014&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y&SECURETOKENID=53bd408f16b490.00182852&TRXTYPE=S

Comment: I'm receiving `false` when checking your code with your postdata string, but no error message

Comment: My password is not the actual password. It returns false may be for this issue. Please check the syntax and tell me whether it is correct or not.

Comment: syntax is ok. do you have '&', '$' or other special characters in your password?

Comment: No. there is no special character in password.Will I have to pass any extra parameter to solve this problem?

Comment: for pretty php code: store this variables in array, for example $postArray = ['USER'=>$PF_USER,'VENDOR'=>$PF_VENDOR,....]
then $post_data = http_build_query($postArray);

Comment: Thanks. I am trying this. After that I will let you know.

Comment: No. Same error displays again. Is there is any merchant account issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions for the user account that you're using in your API requests.  Sounds like maybe the user simply doesn't have access to make API calls.

Login to your http://manager.paypal.com account, go to Account Administration -> Manage Users, and then click into the user that you're working with.

At the bottom you'll see the "Assign privilege to User" section with the following options...

[image]

You need to make sure it's set to API_FULL_TRANSACTIONS, or ADMIN should work, too.

Can you confirm that setting?

Comment: Yes, It is set to ADMIN.

Comment: Ok, well, you did get rid of the space, right?  That error is pretty straight forward.  Something has got to be wrong with those values.  Can you post a sample of the raw request you're getting ending up with?